# Postgres SQL - IN(..) AS... in Select

Tags: sql, postgresql

Can someone help me undertsand the IN(...) AS... in the select. This is the first time I'm seeing something like this. Also, how does the database determine the row value or newID? This is on Postgres datababse.

```
SELECT  tbl_a.*, (
        tbl_z.z_id IN (
            SELECT x_id
            FROM table_x 
            WHERE name = '...'
            )
        ) AS newID
FROM (...)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second column is the answer to the question "is tbl_z.z_id in the list of x_id from table_x where name = '...'?"

As that's a yes/no question (which 'IN' always means), it's a boolean (either true or false).

The "AS" clause tells it what to name that column (it's not directly from a table, so it doesn't know what to call it). It's not strictly required, but it makes addressing that column in your output much easier, you can also use it if you want the column name to be different then the name in the table you're coming from (if you're joining two tables, and they happen to have each have a column with the same names is a use case for this).

Comment: So what is the IN (...) AS is converted into the WHERE clause, and how different the data would looks like?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't really understand your question here. You can't put this into a WHERE clause, because you're doing operations to generate that column, rather then just pulling from a column.

Answer (score 2):

newId will be of type boolean.
true, if

```
tbl_z.z_id IN (
            SELECT x_id
            FROM table_x 
            WHERE name = '...'
            )
```

and false if not.

AS column_name is alias.

**update**
answering your comment.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-WHERE

> where condition is any expression that evaluates to a result of type
>   boolean.

So if you have `IN (...)` in `WHERE` it returns same boolean as in column list. True or false. No difference - `where` or as column, returns either true or false

Comment: So what is the IN (...) AS is converted into the WHERE clause, and how different the data would looks like?